# Attempting to create a dynamic data range for an existing pivot table report using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to craft vba code that will allow my pivot table report range to be dynamically updated for data that is held in another sheet in the excel file. Nb the data in the datasheet, in the database is restricted to 48 columns from column A. The first set of data is stored in A1 + currently the datasheet has 30,000 rows. The code I've crafted from various sites. The code does create any range at all. Can you please help.

```
        Dim DBs As Worksheet
        Dim PTs As Worksheet
        Dim StartPoint As Range
        Dim DataRange As Range
        Dim PivotName As String
        Dim NewRange As String



'Set Variables Equal to Data Sheet and Pivot Sheet


    Set DBs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Spend_DBase")
        Set PTs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("BS_Outstanding spending")



'Enter in Pivot Table Name
    PivotName = "PivotTable1"

'Dynamically Retrieve Range Address of Data


    Set StartPoint = DBs.Range("A1")
        Set DataRange = DBs.Range(StartPoint, StartPoint.End(xlDown).Offset(0, 48))



'Change Pivot Table Data Source Range Address


    Pivot_sht.PivotTables(PivotName).ChangePivotCache _
           ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
           SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
           SourceData:=NewRange)
```

Comment: `SourceData:=NewRange` - did you mean to use `DataRange` ?

Comment: Hi Tim, I did want to use SourceData. I have subsequently found out that the issue was that the Pivot name I defined in my initial Dim statement was inconsistent with the name I was using the section of the code where I was altering the pivot table range.

Comment: `NewRange` is an empty string, so it's not clear why you assign that to `Sourcedata`...

Comment: If without vba, you can make a dynamic named range as the source for the Pivot Table. Something like :`=OFFSET(DATA!$A$1,0,0,COUNTA(DATA!$A:$A),18)` put in the Excel Name Manager formula box. `DATA!` is the name of the sheet. `$A$1` is the starting cell of the data source. `18' is the last column of the data source (18 = column S). So, the data source range is from cell A1 to whatever row of column S. The data source named range will grow/shrink dynamically. But then you need to refresh the pivot table after the source data is updated.